# Open file in the default application WinForms (.NET Core)

Tags: winforms, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I decided to migrate one of the old application to a Windows Forms App (.NET Core).

Previously (in the Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)) I was able to use the following code to open a file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

But migrated application (targeting netcoreapp3.1) throws exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'
```

I plan to use the application on Windows stations.

How can I make this work?
Maybe there is a replacement for this code?

Comment: And what is `filePath`?

Comment: Application uses regular path: "D:\\20150121_190627.jpg"